# What's the purpose of the curly braces after a perl -e line

Tags: perl, find

I know some real perl basics, and I've been using this one liner to rename files:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -e 'rename($_,lc) for @ARGV' {} \;
```

The find passes a list of files to the perl one liner, which then renames them lowercase -- but whats the `{}` for?

Comment: In this case `find` is _not_ passing a list of files, it is running the perl command once for each file found.

Comment: @evil, indeed. Quite expensive, I'd go with xargs.

Comment: @sidyll - or just use `File::Find` or `find2perl`

Comment: @sidyll, or check if the installed `find` supports the `-exec command {} +` syntax.

Comment: If you're on a system that supports GNU `find` (e.g. linux), changing `\;` for `+` will be more efficient. Right now, `@ARGV` only ever has one argument. See `find`'s man page.

Comment: @cespinoza, So? rename: 0.1 ms. Starting Perl 5.0 ms. And he clearly meant to accept more than one arg based on the particular use of `@ARGV`.

Comment: @ikegami: Good addition. I didn't know about `+` and always piped the output to `xargs`. Since `+` is equivalent this means one saved process, yay.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The '`{}`' argument is part of the "find" command, not the "perl" command.

Per the [find man page documentation](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find), the token '`{}`' is replaced with the name of the current file being processed so it can be used by the target of the "exec" arguments, which are, in this case, "`perl -e ...`".

Answer (score 3):

It comes from find, and will be substituted by the file(s) name found. It will execute perl like:

> `perl -e 'rename($_,lc) for @ARGV'`*filename*